# "another way for achieving" vs "another way of achieving"

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

Should it be **for** or **of**? And why?

1. I have to find another way for achieving success.
2. I have to find another way of achieving success.

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done to solve your problem. Have you tried a dictionary? What did you find? Have you tried looking up similar phrases in google? What did you find? Have you tried google books or google news? Also, tell us which you think is correct, and why. Without "research effort" this question is likely to get closed. See [Please, everyone … details. Please!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of both sentences are same

But,
 first one is not commonly used

second one is better